# How to set value of environment value based on install dir

Tags: wix

In a Wix installer xml file, when creating an environment variable, how can I set the value of the env var based on the install directory that the user selected?

Currently, I have something like this, and the part I'm missing is ???:

```
<Component Id='CompId' Guid='xxx'>
  <File Id='ProgramEXE' Name='foo.exe' DiskId='1' Source='foo.exe' KeyPath='yes' />
  <Environment Id='FooInstall' Action='set' Name='FOO_INSTALL' Value='???'/>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Environment table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368369(v=vs.85).aspx)'s Value column is of type [Formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx).  Directory table entries become properties during CostFinalize so therefore you can just say [DIRECTORYNAME] such as [INSTALLLOCATION].